# Concatenating rows using group by and aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine we have a table such as:

```
Number Value GroupValue
1      FOO    GR1
22     BAR    GR2
100    FOO3   GR1
20     BAR23  GR2
```

I want to get the sum values of these rows based on group value,but also ,i want to see which rows it has grouped by in another column such as:

```
SUM  values groups
101  FOO,FOO3 GR1
42   BAR,BAR23 GR2
```

How can i achieve that in sql?

Tried:

```
> SELECT  SUM(ID) AS SUM ,
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + A
                FROM    dbo.Table_1 AS T2
                WHERE   A = T2.A
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '') AS A ,
        B
FROM    dbo.Table_1 AS T
GROUP BY B ,
        A
```

But this can not handle the groups properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an alias created in the `SELECT` list in your `GROUP BY`.
You can fix this by separating your listing from your aggregation (cte/subquery):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT  *
                     ,STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + Value
                              FROM    Table1 AS T2
                              WHERE   T.GroupValue = T2.GroupValue
                              FOR XML PATH('')
                            ), 1, 1, '') AS Value_List
              FROM    Table1 AS T)
SELECT  SUM(Number) AS Total
       ,Value_List
       ,GroupValue
FROM cte
GROUP BY Value_List, GroupValue
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e531/8/0)

Or you can use a partitioned `SUM()` (window function):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT SUM(Number) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupValue) AS Total
        ,STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + Value
                 FROM    Table1 AS T2
                 WHERE   T.GroupValue = T2.GroupValue
                 FOR XML PATH('')
               ), 1, 1, '') AS Value_List
        ,GroupValue
FROM    Table1 AS T
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e531/10/0)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a small change, stick your SQL **without** the group into another select with the group.  I think I converted your SQL right:

```
SELECT SUM(ID) as IdSum, B FROM (
SELECT  ID,
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + A
                FROM    dbo.Table_1 AS T2
                WHERE   A = T2.A
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '') AS B
FROM    dbo.Table_1 AS T) AS B2
GROUP BY B
```

Comment: The problem is trying to group on a "Calculated" field. The nested select allows you group on the result.  This can be done with APPLY as well but this example is easier for most people to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest the list one level deeper

...

```
SELECT
    IDList1=    
        SUBSTRING((
            SELECT  ', ' + CAST(TargetID AS NVARCHAR(10))
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                   DISTINCT TargetID 
                FROM 
                   TargetTable 
                WHERE 
                  TargetIDTableField2=MAINQUERYALIAS.TargetIDTableField2
            )
            AS UP2
            ORDER BY 
             TargetID FOR XML PATH( '' )
        ), 3, 1000 )
FROM
(
   ...
) AS MAINQUERYALIAS
```

Answer (score 0):

download this and run this script http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/releases/view/106409
and you can solve your problem as simple as this

```
select SUM(Number), dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(Value)
from Table_2 
group by GroupValue
```

please mark as answered if this answer ur question thanks